# Really big HTML and Javascript to PHP variable

Tags: php, html, variables

I have got a Html and Javascript code, that contains about 1000 lines and I need to put it to php variable.
Sure I was thinking about the EOT method, But there is one problem with it, if there is word function like in javascript is, it will take it like php function, and this will cause errors.
Any other Idea how to do it?
I have already tried other forums, but they can't help me, so I hope they can help me on the best.

Comment: so where is this code? or a snippet of the problem?

Comment: Maybe [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use output buffering...

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<b>
    <u>
        <font color="#FF0000">
            <blink>
                <marquee>
                    1000
                    LINES
                    OF
                    HTML
                    AND
                    JAVASCRIPT!
                </marquee>
            </blink>
        </font>
    </u>
</b>
<?php
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
?>
```

Then your HTML and JavaScript will be in the `$content` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could read directly from an HTML file on disk, using [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: Yes, I know, but there must be some php variables too :) I know, it's complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EOF method.
There's no problem with reserved words in that case. (As far as I know)

EDIT:

```
$output .= <<<HTML

function bla()
{
 //Something
}

HTML;
```

Won't be treated as a php function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
class Temp
{
   public function html($path) 
   {
     ob_start()

     require(path); // or file_get_contents(<URI>);

    $html = ob_get_clean ();

    return $html

    }

}

   $temp = new Temp(); 
   $htmlData  = $temp->html('somepath/somefile.php') 
   echo $htmlData;
```